# Limite de conexões

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird, conexão, firebird-2.5

Sistema em *Delphi* - Banco de dados *Firebird* 2.5.

Tenho um servidor com 25 "arquivos" de bancos de dados, um de cada cliente.
Cada cliente tem em media 10 acessos via *TS* para conectar em nosso servidor.

Porém, quando chega o horário de pico perto de 16hs, alguns bancos ficam *Off-line* e o sistema perde a conexão com ele.

Existe uma maneira de configurar o Firebird para limitar as conexões com o banco de dados?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o portal firebase ([link](http://www.firebase.com.br)) "depende da arquitetura utilizada (SuperServer, Classic, SuperClassic), SO, método de conexão (tcp/ip, xnet, etc) e até mesmo o poder de processamento do hardware envolvido".

Na versão SuperServer e SuperClasse até a versão 2.5.2 ( SO Windows ) 1024 conexões. Nas versões mais novas foi ampliado para 2048 conexões.

Sugiro que para cada banco de dados você instancie um processo do firebird rodando, e cada um em uma porta diferente.
As configurações de porta podem ser modificadas no arquivo firebird.conf no diretório de instalação.

Recomendo que se inscreva no portal firebase, exitem muitos artigos e dicas para a comunidade que usa o firebird.

Answer (score 1):

Não há limites de conexão no Firebird em si. Ainda assim outros fatores podem limitar o número de conexões permitidas. Veja:

### Sistema Operacional

A maior parte dos sistemas possuem um limite de 1024 conexões simultâneas por porta TCP/IP. Para superar essa limitação você precisaria de criar um sistema n-tier ou pooling de conexão.

### Classic Server

Esse modo geralmente funciona via xinetd ou inetd que possuem sua própria configuração e controle de acesso. Por isso é necessário verificar as configurações, principalmente no caso de usar um terminal service.[Sugestão de leitura](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq161/)

### Limitação de memória

Visto que um processo de 32 bits tem um limite de memória RAM que pode alocar, a versão SuperServer do Firebird terá um limite de conexões.

### Referências

http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq292/